# WebAPI Controller GetAll or Get some Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a controller like this

```
[Route("api/Foo/MyController/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
   //Code code
   foo(id); // Foo accept Int or Null
}
```

This do work, if call **api/Foo/MyController/1**, but i needed call **api/Foo/MyController** like it "GetAll" the parameter id now is null and the stuff into controller return all, how go there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a new method and route:

```
[Route("api/Foo/MyController")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   //Code code
}
```

Edit: to reuse the same method you could use optional parameters:

```
    [Route("api/Foo/MyController/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int? id)
    {
        if (id.HasValue)
        {
           // get by id
        } 
        else
        {
           // get all
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. Sure, but i think, exist some way include this in the same Get, not another Get. Regards

Comment: @nimeshjm is absolutely correct here. You _could_ use a default value and combine everything into a single API but it's more common to separate out the two (especially since the code blocks retrieving the data will be different).

Answer (score 8):

Why don't have 2 separate methods:

```
[Route("api/Foo/")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
{
   // code
}

[Route("api/Foo/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetById(int id)
{
   // code
}
```

For clarity (readability, maintainability, supportability).

Answer (score 2):

You could do also a optional parameter:

```
[Route("api/Foo/MyController/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int? id = null)
{
    IQueryable foo = GetData();
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        foo = foo.Where(e => e.Id == id.Value);
    }
    //...
}
```